# Why does the Zygote creat the socket in the Java level?

Tags: android

I trace the Zygote process. It will jump to the ZygoteInit.java main() function. In this main function it will call the registerZygoteSocket() function. This function will call back the listen function in the C++ level. I am curious if google change the process to run the listen before jumping into the ZygoInit.java main function. It will be more reasonable and faster. Right? Is there any reason for this design?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the main() function of app_main.cpp, you can roughly understand.

```
if (zygote) {
    // Zygote process init
    runtime.start("com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit", args, zygote);
} else if (className) {
    // Application Init
    runtime.start("com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit", args, zygote);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Only the Zygote process will run into this ZygoteInit, other application processes (stand alone, non zygote, application not forked from zygote) run into another path RuntimeInit. But before the execution of Java init, all the C code is common, basically they are doing android runtime stuff, for example, creating VM, allocating gc heap, and art preloading.
Apparently android don't want RuntimeInit to registerZygoteSocket.

Another evidence is after a application process is forked from zygote.

```
private Runnable handleChildProc(ZygoteArguments parsedArgs, FileDescriptor[] descriptors,
        FileDescriptor pipeFd, boolean isZygote) {
    /**
     * By the time we get here, the native code has closed the two actual Zygote
     * socket connections, and substituted /dev/null in their place.  The LocalSocket
     * objects still need to be closed properly.
     */
    closeSocket();
}
```

It will close all the current sockets first. The reason of doing this should be simple, because android app is using binder for IPC, not socket, for an normal app, there is no need to use socket. 
But why we need socket for Zygote process? Because before System Server process(One of Zygote process also) is started, there is no service at all. Only after System Server is created, and all the services are created, the binder can bind to all those services.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for memory efficiency, we delay using resources until we actually need them right? The same applies here. The zygote socket is registered just before we need to start listening to it. Also, we don't expect any commands to be written to socket until zygote is ready to accept them.